# Chosen plugin not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to make use of the chosen plugin, and for some reason, it refuses to apply to my dropdowns. Nothing on the dropdown changes from before I attempted to use it, to after.
Here is the HTML from the view I am using:

```
@model PnPMeetUp.Models.Employee
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
@{
      ViewBag.Title = "Temp";
 }
 <link href="~/Content/Chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("dropdownA").chosen({ width: "95%" });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
      <h2>Temp</h2>
      using (Html.BeginForm())
      {
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
          <label>Select Attendees</label>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.allEmployees, "Id", "Fullname"), new { id = "dropdownA" })
       }
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is a picture of what my view looks like both before and after attempting the plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite simple, your jQuery selector is not returning any matching element:

```
$("dropdownA").chosen({ width: "95%" });
```

You should be using:

```
$("#dropdownA").chosen({ width: "95%" });
```

Notice that the hashtag/pound symbol means:

> [Select a single element with the given id attribute.](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Also, note that the `Employee` class should not contain the list of the employees. That task is much more suited to the `ViewBag`

Comment: Thank you so much. Have literally been sitting for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Kestrel If this reply answered your question. You should click the gray tick at the left-hand side to accept it.